# Entry node on virtualbox with linux on usb?

Tags: linux, node, entry

How to make and run up entry (or relay) node of tor on virtualbox with linux on usb ? Will it work same as node, installed and ran on usual computer (on host) with linux? Should I install and run up node same method as node on host? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work and it will be the same as running it directly on a laptop.

There are some caveats though:

Tor expects nodes to be stable. If you are regularly rebooting your laptop or VM or removing the USB, then this isn't a stable connection and the relay will never see much traffic.

A better option would be to just install Tor on a cheap dedication machine like a raspberry pi and just let it run without interruption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no way to install a tor on a dedication machine and let it run without interruption, but I want make a favor to the development of tor. I will reboote VM and remove USB 2-3 times a day. Will it stable (will people be able to use my relay at this time as well (or slightly less people) than other relays and transmit traffic through it?)? Maybe fewer users will use it, but, as I understand it, it will work? If at this time at least 20-30 users can transmit traffic through it and I will make their use a bit more accessible, that's fine.

Comment: With that instability i would be surprised if you had traffic at all.